# ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly missing

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create EF Core 3.1 context with readonly application intent for connection redirection to replica database.
When context's .ctor are called, connection string in `SqlServerOptionsExtension` extension of  `DbContextOptions` has no `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` option.

Example code:

Startup.cs

```
protected override void DoEndConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<ReadOnlyContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer("...;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly");
        }, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
}
```

ReadOnlyContext.cs

```
public class ReadOnlyContext : DbContext
{
    protected MovedContext(DbContextOptions<MovedContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

I have tried to set up connection in `OnConfiguring` method and it worked as intended.
How i could pass readonly connection string to context upon creating it from `Startup` class?